# Unable to import library errors while using conda environments from GitHub Codespaces

Tags: python, github, anaconda, github-codespaces

I'm seeing `Unable to import 'PACKAGE'` errors when using Codespaces:
[image]

As you see here, I have the IDE set up to use the right conda environment (dev):
[image]

I also verified that the packages are installed with `conda list`: [image]

Restarting, Rebuilding or just creating a new Codespaces isn't helping either. I am able to run `python app.py` and it runs just fine.